# React Native Image not showing up

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, jsx

I am trying to load image from openweather Api But its not laoding up

```
  <View
    style={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    }}>
    <_Text text={location_name} fontSize={36} />
    <Image
      source={{uri: src}}
      alt="hello"
      onLoadEnd={() => {
        console.log('Image :Loaded');
      }}
      onLoadStart={() => {
        console.log('Load start');
      }}
      height={100}
      width={100}
      style={{width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
      resizeMode="cover"
    />
  </View>
```

this is my current code and even alt is not showing up . Do we need to configure anysetting before using images in config

I have tried various page which has try puttin width and height options but they too didnt work!
when i call onLoad it runs =>
on onLoadEnds doesnt run !

Comment: what your `src` looks like?

Comment: put your code in a snack -> https://snack.expo.dev/@injecteer/homer-image and it's showing the image like charm